# Python: Iterating through user defined Oracle PL/SQL types

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm trying to work with an Oracle system entirely accessed through an api (no direct access to tables).
The Oracle side is built like this:

```
create or replace package Chb_pythontest
  authid definer
as
  type Python_test_rec is record
  (
    Io_var    number,
    Var1      number
  );
  type Python_test_tab is table of Python_test_rec
    index by binary_integer;

  procedure Test_output_collection (Io_id            in     number,
                                    Out_test_table      out Python_test_tab);
end Chb_pythontest;
```

It works fine using this Python-code:

```
conn = co.connect(CONN_STR)
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    collection_type = conn.gettype("CHB_PYTHONTEST.PYTHON_TEST_TAB")
    collection = collection_type.newobject()
    cursor.callproc("Chb_pythontest.Test_output_collection", [1, collection])          

    ix = collection.first()
    while ix is not None:
        record = collection.getelement(ix)
        print("Rownum: ", ix)
        print(">> IO_VAR -> ", record.IO_VAR)
        print(">> VAR1 -> ", record.VAR1)
        ix = collection.next(ix)
```

It obviously knows that there's an IO_VAR and VAR1 in the record-element, but only because i explicitly refer to them. I have found no way to iterate through it dynamically. Converting it to a list or dict would be ideal.

Do i need to create my own iterator or can it be done using cx_oracle or similar?

Comment: Does this function to dump the contents of an Oracle object help: https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/8.2.1/samples/tutorial/solutions/bind_sdo.py#L53-L79

Answer (score 0):

You *can* currently iterate over the cx_Oracle Object attributes, but it's a private method, so it's a bit of a hack. If you take an introspective look at the `cx_Oracle.Object` with:

```
dir(collection.getelement(1))
```

You can see all the methods available to use. The one interesting to us here is `__getattribute__()` - pass in an attribute name, and you can get the value dynamically, instead of using `object.ATTRIBUTENAME`.

We'll also need the names of the attributes ("columns") in the object type (IO_VAR and VAR1, in this example). You can get them from `collection_type.element_type.attributes`.

Putting that all together, we can either run through it in a print loop, like your code:

```
for r in range(1,collection.size()):
    record = collection.getelement(r)
    print(f"Rownum: {r}")
    for k in collection_type.element_type.attributes:
        print(f">> {k.name} -> {record.__getattribute__(k.name)}")
```

Or turn the whole collection into a list of dicts (with rather cumbersome list/dict comprehensions).

```
pycollection = [{k.name: collection.aslist()[r].__getattribute__(k.name) for k in collection_type.element_type.attributes} for r in range(collection.size())]
print(pycollection)
```

It can be a bit slow with a large collection; there might be a better option available that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it seems to be pretty much in the ballpark of what i was looking for. It does indeed seem to be a rather cumbersome solution, so i might solve it on the oracle-end instead by overloading it with a function that returns json or somesuch. Regardless, thanks :)